# login with asp.net membership cross domain authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am using one membership database for different domain. When I login in one domain, I want to automatically also perform a login for different domain in same browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have same domain name, but sub-domain name different, you can handle this authentication.

Answer (score 1):

i refer this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

i think there is no solution for it